# DKIM in both sandbox and production

Tags: sandbox, dkim

So someone in our past setup DKIM in the production system.  Now I have a sandbox and I'm testing emailing.  I need DKIM setup in the sandbox as well.

Can I just setup DKIM in the sandbox with the same values (selector, keysize, that stuff) as we have in production and will that be enough to get emails signed and not flagged as spam?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I read that entry and all of the documents that it referenced.  Honestly I'm completely stupid about this stuff.  In our production system we have DKIM setup.  So I was really looking for a simple 'Yes just enter the same things you see in production, or NO, the process is much more complex'.  And if it's more complex maybe there is a good SFDC hero that has written about how to set this up.